# Tunelling over HTTP

Tags: http, tunneling, http-proxy, remote-desktop

I have a network at work that is locked behind a firewall and Internet connection is available only by using a proxy server. At work, I can connect to databases that are distributed across the network.

However, at home, I cannot connect to the proxy server or the databases.

How can this be done? I can access my workstation via LogMeIn, so I can install anything on it.

I thought of installing some kind of tunneling mechanism in my workstation. Then, at home, I could connect to this mechanism, which would in turn do the required connections.

So essentially, what I'd like to do can be represented by the following diagram: `Home => Workstation => Database`. For example, whenever I connect to, say, 10.140.0.1:1234 at home, this would be redirected to 10.140.0.1:1234 of my Workstation, because 10.140.0.1:1234 is only available through the corporate network.

Note: I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Would running potential security-bypassing software on your workstation violate company policy?

Comment: That would not be a problem. I already have LogMeIn installed, and no one raised a problem. However, that is too slow to work. Now, I can either go to office this weekend, or do the job at home (which would be much better).

Comment: Do you have direct access to the work PC from the internet or is it behind a NAT/Firewall?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get OpenSSH onto your workstation computer (say, with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/)'s `openssh` package), you can use a proxy helper named [`corkscrew`](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) to enable the OpenSSH client to tunnel out through the proxy. Cygwin has a `corkscrew` package, so it's convenient to use if you already have Cygwin installed. Read the `corkscrew` man page for instructions on its configuration (I believe it's a simple one-line addition to `/etc/ssh_config`).

Next, you'll need to make your home PC a viable endpoint for ssh client connections from the workstation, and for that, you need to be running an sshd daemon. Again, Cygwin is one place to get it: Install the `openssh` package, and then run the `ssh-host-config` script to create the sshd service. Accept the default answers to each of the config script's questions.

Since your home PC is behind a NAT router (right?), forward TCP port 22 to your PC, and add that port as an exception to your PC's firewall. **This is a security risk,** so take appropriate precautions (left as an exercise).

Finally, to create a tunnel to transport connections to your corporate database from your home PC: Login to your workstation (via LogMeIn), and open a tunnel back to your home PC, as follows (in a Cygwin bash shell):

```
ssh -N -R 1234:10.140.0.1:1234 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where `username` is the name of the user to connect to your sshd server, and `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the real, routable IP address of your home router. Any connections you make to `localhost:1234` on your home PC will be forwarded over the tunnel to `10.140.0.1:1234`, and thus it will appear as though the corporate database is listening on your home PC's TCP port 1234. When you're done, you can close the tunnel by killing the `ssh` command on your workstation with a Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I did the following: 1) Installed Cygwin with `openssh` at my *Home PC*; 2) Installed an SSH client (`putty`) at my *Workstation*, and configured it to do the equivalent of your `ssh` command and `corkscrew`, i.e., configured the proxy, and remote tunnel (R1234 => 10.140.0.1:1234). I can connect from `Workstation` to my `Home PC's` SSH server. However, when I attempt to login to the database from my Home PC (using localhost:1234), I get an I/O exception. If I try to use `ssh -v -p 1234 localhost` I get `Connection Established` and an error.

Comment: The error is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I searched for this error, and everyone suggests problems with /etc/hosts.allow|denny, but I don't even have these files at Cygwin. Do you know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Unless the server at 10.140.0.1:1234 is an sshd daemon, using the ssh client on your home PC is not a useful way to test the tunnel. Try something simpler, like `telnet localhost 1234` or `nc localhost 1234`.